# How to find the create CallSite of a specific function in LLVM

Tags: llvm

Generally, I see many people using :

```
 CallSite CS(function->use_back());
```

to create callsite.
However, `use_back()` seems not appear in the lately released `LLVM`. So how can achieve the same goal in the newest `LLVM`.

Answer (score 0):

How about `Value::uses()`.Remember to take care of `ConstantExpr`s and whatnot because in some cases the functions will go through a `BitCastConstantExpr` before being called